# Uploading images in meteor js bundle folder on linux server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor, filesystems

I'm on Windows and develop meteor project. When i need to upload public media i put it in public folder. After compilation to production on vps server with ubuntu i have tar.gz file which extracting into bundle.

So there is no public folder in a bundle, and all preloaded media placing at web.browser and web.browser.legacy folders in this bundle with access urls like "www.example.com/image.jpg".

I tried upload images into these folders (web.browser and web.browser.legacy) but urls doesn't work with new files. The question is why? And how i can set urls for another folder on server out of bundle and make it public *because of all files will be removed after rebundle* ?

Comment: Files in the public folder don't get removed when you run `meteor build`, something seems to be wrong with your bundling, or you are making wrong assumptions. If you have `file123.xyz` in `public`, then after the bundle is unpacked and started the way it is described in the included README file, then `yoururl/file123.xyz` should give you the file.

Comment: I mean public folder works fine in dev but after bundling a project on linux i can't upload new files that will be given by yoururl/newfile.xyz

Comment: that might be correct, you cannot simply add new files to the public folder once it is deployed. Then indeed I think you want to look for how to serve static files. There are answer on that here, too.

Answer (score 0):

[Meteor-Files package](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files) works ok with that. Problem was i couldn't find download urls for uploaded images, answers is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452745/meteor-files-storing-a-image-url-in-mongo-collection), thx for that.

Default url is "example.com/cdn/storage/Images/image-collection-id/orignal/image-collection-id.extension"